# solution for selecting checkbox on datagridview

Tags: c#

i am using following code when inserting check box column to datagridview,

`DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);`

when i am trying to select checkbox, it is not selectecd (not checked or unchecked),
is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish for that `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`? please add some more details

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding a column in gridview but on assigning a datasource you gridview. Bind the gridview with datasource to access the rows to check or uncheck the checkboxes.

**Edit** based on comments.

You can use RowDataBound event to enable/disable  checkboxes using row instances of grid view with data source data during bihnding.

```
void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
       CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkBoxID");
       if(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "datasourceColumnName").ToString() == "someval")
             chk.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: after binding data to gridview, i added this checkboxcolumn, during runtime data and corresponding checkboxes are seen but i am trying to selecting that some checkbox this checkbox are never checked(selected), it remains uncheck mode

Answer (score 0):

u can use this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/MohanKumar.R/selecting-checkboxes-inside-the-gridview-control/)

```
rotected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check for the row type, which should be data row
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Find the check boxes and assign the values from the data source
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)[1]);
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd")).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)[2]);
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkEdit")).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)[3]);
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAll")).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)[4]);

            //Find the checkboxes and assign the javascript function which should
            //be called when the user clicks the checkboxes.

            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkBoxClicked('" +
((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd")).ClientID
+ "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkEdit")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAll")).ClientID + "'," + "'SELECT')");

            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkBoxClicked('" +
((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd")).ClientID
+ "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkEdit")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAll")).ClientID + "'," + "'ADD')");

            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkEdit")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkBoxClicked('" +
((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd")).ClientID
+ "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkEdit")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAll")).ClientID + "'," + "'EDIT')");

            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAll")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkBoxClicked('" +
((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAdd")).ClientID
+ "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkEdit")).ClientID + "','" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAll")).ClientID + "'," + "'ALL')");

        }
    }
```